# No graph output when using googleVIS in jupyter

Tags: r, server, httpserver

Using this works in R console:

```
plot(G)
```

but when typed into a cell in jupyter I get:

```
starting httpd help server ... done
```

and no graph. 
So here is what I did.
Into Anaconda 2.7.11, I installed R essentials

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

started up jupyter

```
notebook jupyter
```

installed needed reqs, XML and googleVIS, by typing this into a cell

```
options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="https://cloud.r-project.org/")))
install.packages('googleVis')
install.packages('XML')
```

typed this code into a cell

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(googleVis))
library(googleVis)
library(XML)
url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_credit_rating"
x <- readHTMLTable(readLines(url), which=3)
levels(x$Rating) <- substring(levels(x$Rating), 4, 
                            nchar(levels(x$Rating)))
x$Ranking <- x$Rating
levels(x$Ranking) <- nlevels(x$Rating):1
x$Ranking <- as.character(x$Ranking)
x$Rating <- paste(x$Country, x$Rating, sep=": ")
G <- gvisGeoChart(x, "Country", "Ranking", hovervar="Rating",
                options=list(gvis.editor="S&P",
                             projection="kavrayskiy-vii",
                             colorAxis="{colors:['#91BFDB', '#FC8D59']}"))
```

then

```
plot(G)
```

This code works fine when typed directly into an R console and makes a nice map. But something is causing jupyter to choke on starting a server. I guess since jupyter itself is web page running in a server there is some sort of problem with a web page starting a server?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. According to [this demonstration](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_googleVis_with_knitr.html), all you need in an R console is to additionally add this line after loading the library:

```
library(googleVis)
op <- options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')
```

The introduction of `tag` can also be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis.pdf) in googleVis's documentation. After trying it in Jupyter all I got is a block of .json data and it cannot compile into an interactive graph.

Hope this help in anyway. I will probably try something like `plotly`, which does work on `jupyter`.

Comment: that's what i did. plotly.

Comment: Neither link works. The page seems to have been abandoned. after adding options=op, i get a block of html code. Definitely not good for production or automation.